# What's the difference between a translation request w/ the user's own attempt, and a proofreading question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I just saw [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47089/9749) in the close review queue. At first I was going to vote "leave open", because the asker gave their own attempt (which makes it allowed, I think). But I noticed the asker also used the words "proof read", which made me realize that it is a *proofreading* question, which is off-topic.

It's really confusing because translation questions are usually off-topic... except for sometimes. The community (myself included) has been pretty inconsistent on which questions count as off-topic translations and which count as on-topic ones. Part of the reason for that, I assume, is because the lines are blurry.

Is there some kind of consensus we can come to?

Comment: I think a "proofreading" question is one that asks "Is this translation correct?" An on-topic question asks "This is my translation. Is this use of [word/phrase/grammatical structure/etc.] correct? Here is why I think it might not be." An on-topic question should ask a question related to an own translation attempt.

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean that when people say "please provide your own attempt or this will be closed as off-topic translation request", doing that wouldn't actually fix the question?

Comment: Depends. Sometimes there is a question but no translation. In these cases the question just reads "Please translate this sentence for me, especially this one part." Giving an own translation could salvage the question by putting it closer to the form in my previous comment.

Comment: Also, how come [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/close/13177) was voted to be left open then, since the asker only gave their own translation (and nothing else)?

Comment: I can't speak for other people, but since most of the sentence is correct (and easy), I understood the question to be "is テストにする a correct way to say *to take a test*". I agree that the question could be improved by making this explicit.